# How to avoid reading empty rows in pandas.read_excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel sheet that contains one million rows. Only the first hundred rows or so have data. Remaining rows are empty and blank. pandas.read_excel internally makes use of xlrd to read data. In turn xlrd reads the whole sheet and takes a lot of time(Around 65 seconds). I tried the below code. But could not reduce the reading time.

```
df= pd.read_excel(file_path, sheetname=sheetname,nrows=1000, skiprows=1, header=None)
```

I have a 8GB RAM in my machine with Windows 10 OS.
I'm using pandas 0.25.3

Is there any other optimal solution to reduce reading time ?

Answer (score 6):

`keep_default_na=False` parameter may reduce read time and ignore the NaN values in excel file.

Example usage:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', keep_default_na=False)
```

Comment: This helps... Got time reduced from 65 secs to 54 secs.....But, I wish to have around 5 to 10 secs....

Comment: As far as i know `read_csv` is working faster than `read_excel` so if you are able to open excel file and save it as CSV file this might help you.

Comment: Yes, I saw a few question posts with conversion to csv solution. I will try them. Thanks

Comment: Read_csv is faster. Thanks !