# pd.read_excel reading not required empty cells using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, nan

Whenever I read a .xlsx file using pd.read_excel(), the dataframe contains a lot of empty NaN cells which are not required.

For Eg:

[image]

The above table when read using read_excel should contain only 30 cells (including headers and the empty cell inside the table). but its giving me all the empty cell adjacent to the table with NaN and my dataframe is much bigger in terms of height and width due to empty NaN cells.

I think this is a package problem. Can anyone help ?

Another Eg:

pd.read_excel gave :

[image]

Comment: Please share the output of `read_excel`.

Comment: output for read_excel has been provided above

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is with the excel doc as it is having null data (They are not empty).
You can try using pandas dropna function with parameters as (axis=0, how='all', inplace=True) to remove these rows from the dataframe.

Comment: This problem persists when you use engine='openpyxl' as a parameter in pd.read_excel(). Just to showcase this problem I have used that parameter because the problem is actually happening in my PC2 (problem exists even if I remove the parameter , engine='openpyxl'). But PC1 does not have this problem and I cannot print the data frame in PC2 (assume). So in short, this is not the problem with excel file but in turn the problem with my packages. So I need a fix for that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered @ [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196316/how-to-avoid-reading-empty-rows-in-pandas-read-excel#:~:text=empty%20and%20blank.-,pandas.,time(Around%2065%20seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196316/how-to-avoid-reading-empty-rows-in-pandas-read-excel#:%7E:text=empty%20and%20blank.-,pandas.,time(Around%2065%20seconds)).

Do post here if that solution is not working.

Comment: That solution does not work. I have already tried that solution before.

Comment: I'm running in the same problem. The solution mentioned in the link does not work for me either. When adding the `keep_default_na = True` option, the rows are just empty in print statement instead of showing `NaN`, but still exist as the rownumbers are printed.

Comment: I am dropping those NaN values manually by using  (axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)